# Does anybody recognize this automotive connector?

Tags: connector, automotive, identification

[image]

I'm trying to repair a wiring harness, and I'd rather pin and install a connector than splice into a junkyard pigtail.  Does anyone recognize this and know where to find them?  There's some serious connector-identifying wizards here.

edit:

I know what the usage of the connector is (camshaft for a second-gen Ford Focus).  I'm trying to make my own pigtail for it, so I'll need a blank plug and uncrimped pins.  That's what I'm having trouble finding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a Bosch Jetronic connector.

I have a car full of them.
(Not just used on Jetronic.)

Comment: ... like I said, goddamned wizards.

Comment: I found a set, including boot and pins, for under $20.

Answer (score 5):

Automotive companies design most of their own connectors as custom items.

If you can't find one in the form you want, I suggest you buy the pigtail, disassemble the connector, and post pictures of the terminals - you may find a similar terminal more easily than a similar connector.

Keep in mind that the terminal is specific to the connector specifically, and not just the connector design.  It's possible that if you disassemble the original connector, and a check pigtail connector the terminals will be different.

If you do need to buy more than a few of these without the connected wires, then use alibaba or a similar parts search engine to find companies that make them, and get a quote.  You might find exactly what you need as a pigtail, and they may be able to supply you with the connector parts rather than an assembled version.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what it is, but it is sold on amazon.com: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B000IYHG00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IYHG00)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wanting to make my own pigtail using this connector.

Comment: @insta  If you haven't done this already, ask you local auto mechanics and auto parts shops (small mom&pop ones).  Browse trough [Waytek](http://www.waytekwire.com) catalog too.  Just an $0.02 suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi%3aAMhZZitVhdkwHhHvqLqC8dFOKF5rHMElsXHY6AmFdkRS_1Oq7NdmuGUN6tFY50tC-QelZzTgIX5_18a9jmSFFJQaR8QPWvc6fHQWr3RdPnxpX70CNlu6Z5r1BSJaQ92cj2qXDb0FQlr0iErmhALE6iZbyfozMIhQLiMNCa4GH2W1kthCai5E8DqiFGNSQjIHFFjImHDMYyr1JuoU-9zNyqyaE7JGIg4O4M0SKFnYaemFwMPZ_1xdeZwjzcA1d5Rghse0Ko0EU904_18h9yfRGcMNa91dn7RKEOzHNfQvNmEgcP6cqIk0ZQ33kIjGGfD8B9Sm4i3BrVweS44IW16EjpAEXCpeTMZo5iptXwsfgSLFUAbk3CWYYkBX3-aD3jMAZZeh3P6tta3N0OMs2yNijJfe0r4FgM8t2KLQwIarEToQXVYeS_1TIQThDrO7L11oVgipdgqNQQW8_1IBQoShOKfMz8M4zQCTEdSzoPe4FMtPNgfDOmpt_1FvNUdLE7p4qV9v_1SEOBbNcIGCR0Stlxkdz8mZSynWa6JkZitEKPFNCEIwf5q2FVQDz3MaFpmGKyqcHypg9AP9XMOAbFzML8ASJpOG-XSj3K716Ni04PRX-BkjadxOEBnsz4VOIFvJBHf2E4xMNYMfB74P_1QnlDzs65KfitC-f3zilTyGpZw_1Qm6cPjeZc6bEObudS_1qo_1KC6l5-VN8nZ2VjeBFogNUV6gWb95VWCMOmjgCdBoxrkznJo53RIwFM1BIDrSSSTindp9fhICuW2TzKgKwjqByFdTQOxcl5wDuW_1PPzo8FAxqXyKq6IcW6RHLQUy1b7NLobI0MapRF2pYhJUUR2luIdQZYK2Rjm7eiYth0rWgIwYJeQRbQgSlqhotqDXvbbgT3DKr_1rcwH5HBMypBCIHdehn3obmr2NUzHv7LfJpB_1DB7ou59cCy_16QrL7jVPWK35VQu6GDpi7aLVUmbGjResU3Pxr_1HYpXO3J3CBJFTk12fVsz5gnMZU8zaH9rIR3jiRfARVL5R1QTpzrsVvITbuXqGWktHqyv0RKudfLq_1Uu44BVJZOJP1KOARQcZaQm4NViBb6nzhFliP_1Wotg3uDqy2u_1Mv3qBRoR4VZy-HVvDBt2l8pa2rg6cOFM06Okdc4_1LvtbTQiT27LYdVvRIgWcYXMqjpVo4XNSnYgfoHou-NOrFAosPSq_1_1Rw5N1ZjLMmIpzg7cIrNzfA5BJYMmN2UOawRw3Di636jYV1BIP4ViEiujXwZyyR2FmbRQgp4K9o31ROHtofvYtAxp8WDTsIXd2gxgThRw_14bBJ0nPGtWoomoEIpaOQyguVVxO5o52dowjPmNqC43z6QXRjWVua1FbmpjQc9RhF8LATFtEc_1mgxqGHU2mZmBTHy8nGbgalezPrfhaCPEyJc-j3_14ToWLI&num=10&hl=en&bih=860&biw=1745), it's a [camshaft position sensor connector](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=motorcraft%20wpt717%20motorcraft%20camshaft%20position%20sensor%20connector&sa=X&ei=xVYhULjNMMr50gHAn4DIBA&ved=0CBoQvQ4&biw=1745&bih=860).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wanting to make my own pigtail using this connector.