# Does anybody recognize this (other) automotive connector?

Tags: connector, automotive, identification

[image]

Similar to my [other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37348/does-anybody-recognize-this-automotive-connector), I have another connector I can't identify.  Does anybody recognize the series?  I am wanting to build my own, so I need to know what series it is and what pins it takes.

(yes, I know what it came from.  It's the crank position sensor from a Focus.  I know I can buy premade pigtails.  I'm not asking for either of those bits of information)

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is a (Honda) NH-1 connector. (Sorry, no pointers to the wiring.)

Comment: not a honda nh-1 connector, made by amp but not sure part number

Comment: @suha I would bet that Ford isn't using Honda connectors... just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Motorcraft WPT420 Air Charged Temperature Connector
[http://www.amazon.com/Motorcraft-WPT420-Charged-Temperature-Connector/dp/B000IYHFGU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IYHFGU)

Method of search: Drag and drop the image onto Google Images search

Answer (score 1):

For all the connectors on American car brands, I usually find more often than not that they have a **Delphi/Packard** equivalent.  In particular, you'll see these parts remanufactured under Motorcraft or [insert aftermarket OE replacement parts company here].  They usually end up building them out as pigtail harrnesses for splicing in... which is why you end up having to go back to the original design by someone like Delphi to get the raw connectors and contacts.

So, in short, I'm putting my money on a **Delphi** connector.  The reason I say this is two fold: *connector shape* and *asymmetrical keying*.  AMP/Tyco tend to have more square/rectangular-style connectors with less keying and usually the key oriented on the center line of one of the axes... not asymmetrical as shown here.

Not exactly a full on answer, but more of a what I hope will be a push in the right direction.